# Procedure entry point pthread_mutex_lock could not be found in the DLL

Tags: c++, dll, c++20

I installed GCC 10.2.0 an hour ago and since have been trying to get it to run. The problem I'm encountering every time I build and run my project is:

```
The procedure entry point pthread_mutex_lock could not be located in the dynamic link library
```

I'm using Code::Blocks 20.03 on Windows 8.1 as my IDE. I think I've set everything up exactly the same way I did when I was setting up GCC 9.2.0 a few months back. Simple programs are able to compile and run without any error. As soon as I try using `ranges::sort()` on a vector, I end up getting the above pop-up error and runtime execution exits immediately. I don't even understand the error. How is a mutex_lock coming into the picture? How could I fix the error? Why is it even there?

A simple program that compiles and runs without any error:

```
int main () {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector <int> a (n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> a [i];
    }
//  ranges::sort(a); // once uncommented and compiled again, it fails to run

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << a [i] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I installed again but this time from [WinLibs](http://winlibs.com/) which happens to be built by Brecht Sanders and everything works right after setting up file paths. I don't yet know what causes the above error and would still like to information regarding what could have caused it.

Comment: Now I have cc1plus.exe crashing when working with precompiled headers. The size of my precompiled header is about 150MB. Upon doing some searches on google, I came across an old SO post and redirections to bugzilla. However, it's an old discussion (2015). It mentions that the default max size for pch is `128*1024*1024` (128 MB) which is too small in my case. I could work around by omitting `-g` compilation flag and making my PCH smaller in size to about 80 MB. However, I want to work with the `-g` flag. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Also, if the above problem (in the comment right above this) is a known problem for a long time, why hasn't there been a "real" fix? The code is only going to get bigger in the standard libraries and 128 MB is way too small for PCHs anyways.

Comment: Okay, I'm done. After two hours of trying to make C++20 with PCH work, the best solution I've figured is to not compile with `-g` and remove any debugging options from compilation flag as it's causing a size bloat up. The size of the PCH is down to 120 MB which allows me to compile without crashing cc1plus.exe.

Comment: How did you compile your code? did you pass ***-pthread*** to *GCC*?

Comment: @CristiFati  `g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -Weffc++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -std=c++20 -H -DZ_LOCAL -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. This didn't work before I started using WinLibs installation. After Winlibs installation, everything did work except PCHs of size > 128MB.